# What does it mean to draw a point from a distribution with non-singleton atoms?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

This is a philosophical/pedagogical question. Ordinarily, if $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a probability space, then "drawing random point $X\in\Omega$" means that for each $A\in\mathcal{A}$, the probability of $X$ falling into $A$ is $\mu(A)$. Aside from making intuitive sense, this suggests a quasi-algorithmic sampling process: Finitely partition $\Omega$ into sets of small measure, and draw a partition member from the resulting finite distribution, according to weight under $\mu$.

Now suppose that $\mathcal{A}=2^\Omega$ and that $\mu$ admits non-singleton atoms. The existence of such "monsters" is independent of ZFC and, to take an extreme case, it might be that $\mu(A)\in\{0,1\}$ for all $A\subseteq\Omega$. In such a setting, (how) can one meaningfully speak of drawing a random point $X\in\Omega$ according to $\mu$?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your remark about the "monsters". If $\mu$ admits an atom, then what's the problem? For example, divide $\Bbb R$ into countable intervals, $I_n$, and $\mu(I_n)=\frac1{2^n}$. This is a probability measure, and it has non-singleton atoms.

Comment: Moreover, you are essentially asking what does it mean to have a measure when the measure is binary. And it is the same thing as it would in any other case. It means that given a set, you either almost surely avoid it, or almost surely hit it. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: The problem is imagining a process for drawing such a point. If you tell me that almost surely $X\in A$, that might not be telling me very much. Intuitively, I want "refined" information about where $X$ might or might not land -- and this is ruled out.

Comment: (1) Don't imagine things. (2) If you choose a point in $[0,1]$ randomly, it is almost surely irrational, transcendental, and so on. How is your intuition handling that? The large cardinals, or the appeal to measures "everywhere", is a red herring here. Tell me what it means for a non-Borel set to have measure $\frac12$ in $[0,1]$, and then we can move on to ultrafilters.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I call these monsters because I'm having a lot of trouble wrapping my mind around such objects. Also, I don't understand your first comment. What measure $\mu$ are you defining on (all subsets of?) $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The measure is a counting measure which counts how many of the intervals $I_n$ your set contains, which was modified to be a probability measure.

Comment: Fine, let's take your last example. I can certainly draw an *interval* from this discrete measure -- no problems there. Now, how do I draw a point from this interval?

Comment: Also, I don't buy your comparison to rationals/irrationals. Sure, any measure-zero set, fixed a-priori, will have a zero chance of being hit. It's the idea of approximating by smaller sets that I am having a lot of trouble letting go of.

Comment: I think you are conflating the "drawing process" with the probability. The idea is that if you say "I will choose an arbitrary point", then you can ask what is the probability of it to have come from this or that set. In the case of the atomic measure, a single point has probability $0$. But whether it comes from a set which contains all the intervals except the first, has probability $\frac12$. (Also, I am not "selling" you anything.)

Comment: So you agree that one cannot meaningfully speak of a "drawing process"? (The probability measure is, of course, well-defined; that much was never in dispute.)

Comment: Probability is not about *the drawing process*. It's correlating the possible outcome with certain possible characteristics (e.g. I draw a number between $[0,1]$ what are the odds of it being $<\frac12$, or rational, or the code of a continuous function which is nowhere differentiable, etc. etc.) you need to shed this finitary shell that you're trapped in, where probability is *about* drawing balls from a jar, and by doing so $n$ times you can say whether or not most balls are black or blue.

Comment: "you need to shed this finitary shell that you're trapped in" tell that to Doron Zeilberger. To his face.

Comment: Okay...? I see this conversation has become pointless. Good luck with your future endeavours.